# Unable to remove unicode char from column names in pandas under Python 2.x

Tags: python, pandas, unicode, character-encoding, python-2.x

I have read a csv file in pandas dataframe and am trying to remove the unicode char **u** from the column names but with no luck.

```
fl.columns
Index([ u'time', u'contact', u'address'], dtype='object')

headers=[ 'time', 'contact', 'address']
fl=pandas.read_csv('file.csv',header=None,names=headers)
```

Still doesnt work

```
fl.columns
Index([ u'time', u'contact', u'address'], dtype='object')
```

Even the rename doesnt work either

```
fl.rename(columns=lambda x:x.replace(x,x.value.encode('ascii','ignore')),inplace=True)
fl.columns
Index([ u'time', u'contact', u'address'], dtype='object')
```

Can anybody please tell me why this is happening and how to fix it ? Thanks.

Comment: Please help me on this !!!!

Comment: I think it's only a display problem, you can check the type by `type(fl.columns[0])`.

Comment: type is coming str itself but im not able to run mysql query on this column. q=u"""
SELECT contact FROM fl LIMIT 50
"""    ERROR==== ProgrammingError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str). It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings.

Comment: Does this work: `fl.columns = [col.encode('ascii', 'ignore') for col in fl]`?

Comment: encoding = "ISO-8859-1" worked for me, but then again the silly u is coming with all the column names (u'time', u'contact'). The problem with u is that im not able to call mysql query on these column names due to this unicode u character coming in all the column names. Please help, ive wasted entire day on this "u" thing

Comment: did you try what I suggested?

Comment: This only happens under Python 2.x, right? Hence can be closed. Python 3 text is handled as bytes, not string. Also, the well-known 'ASCII hammer' workaround that @EdChum recommends is ok.

Answer (score 5):

If you really need to remove the `u` (since this is only a display issue) you can do the following **very dirty trick**:

```
from pandas import compat

compat.PY3 = True

df.columns
Index(['time', 'contact', 'address'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: @jsc123
The `compat` module is a collection of functions written in a way that allows them to be compatible with both python 2 and python 3.
As you can see [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/v0.16.2/pandas/compat/__init__.py#L39) `PY3` is just a _boolean flag_, set depending on your python version.

Comment: Without going further, you can already see that overwriting this _flag_ can (and will) have very nasty effects on the rest of your `pandas` code, since from then on, whenever you need to use one of those functions (this might happen internally in `pandas` code) you'll be getting the python 3 compatible version of those functions which are certain to fail or return wrong stuff.

Comment: Seems that this is kind of pandas's bug.
`df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.randn(5), 'b':np.random.randn(5)})`. Then `print df.columns` shows `Index([u'a', u'b'], dtype='object')`, but `type(df.locumns[0])` returns `str`.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with this today and used: `df['var'] = df['var'].astype(str)`

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue while building ML pipeline. My features list was having Unicode along with names.

features

```
[u'Customer_id', u'Age',.....]
```

One way to get away with it is using str() function. Create a new list with applying an str function to each of the value.

```
features_new= [str(x) for x in features]
```

Now the `features_new` list will not have any Unicode char. Let me know how it works.