# Why is Pandas forcing unicode column names in place of strings?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

Why is Pandas force converting ascii strings to unicode upon conversion from dictionary to dataframe? Is this a feature or a known bug?

I'm using Python 2.7.3 and Pandas 0.20.2

MWE included below.

```
import pandas as pd

sample_dict={}
sample_dict['A'] = {'Key_1': 'A1', 'Key-2': 'A2', 'Key_3': 'A3'}
sample_dict['B'] = {'Key_1': 'B1', 'Key-2': 'B2', 'Key_3': 'B3'}
sample_dict['C'] = {'Key_1': 'C1', 'Key-2': 'C2', 'Key_3': 'C3'}
print sample_dict['A'].keys()
sample_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(sample_dict, orient='index')
print sample_df.keys()
```

Results in:

```
['Key-2', 'Key_1', 'Key_3']
Index([u'Key-2', u'Key_1', u'Key_3'], dtype='object')
```

Addendum: I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28535067/unable-to-remove-unicode-char-from-column-names-in-pandas) similar question, but it's been inactive for a couple of years and does not discuss why this is happening.

Comment: just curious, what problems does it cause you, mainly aesthetics?

Comment: Just some annoyance mainly. Instead of being able to access the columns as sample_df['Key_1'], I have to use sample_df[u'Key_1'].

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what would happen if there is a 'Key' and an u'Key' both in the dictionary.

Comment: really? i could access the your example by just sample_df['Key_1'], what environment are you using? I used Jupyter notebook.

Comment: Ok. It seems I can access it without the prefix in the case of MWE. But somehow that does not work for my actual code. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from pandas dataframe repr 
it says

```
    """
    Return a string representation for a particular object.

    Yields Bytestring in Py2, Unicode String in py3.
    """
```

so I am sure in python 3 you should not be able to see any unicode prefix.