# Unable to extract dataframe column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-cleaning

I am new to pandas and am struggling with to rename a column and then extracting the same.

I have read an xls file into a pandas data frame object.

```
df = pd.read_excel("something.xls")
bank_statement.columns.values[0] = 'Din'
bank_statement.columns
```

This showed the columns

```
Index([u'Din', u'Unnamed: 1', u'Unnamed: 2', u'Unnamed: 3', u'Unnamed: 4',
       u'Unnamed: 5', u'Unnamed: 6'],
      dtype='object')
```

But this causes error.

```
bank_statement.Din
```

The error is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-6ce73c262cd1> in <module>()
----> 1 bank_statement.Din

/Users/monideepde/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.pyc in __getattr__(self, name)
   3612             if name in self._info_axis:
   3613                 return self[name]
-> 3614             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   3615 
   3616     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Din'
```

Contrary to this, when I had tried to do the same for a column that was named when it was imported, I did not face any issue.

```
data = pd.read_csv("/somepath/TestFrame.csv")
data
```

[image]

I could access the columns

[image]

Can anyone point out where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: This might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28535067/unable-to-remove-unicode-char-from-column-names-in-pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't update internal Pandas structures using `.values`:

```
bank_statement.columns.values[0] = 'Din'
```

Use corresponding API function/method instead:

```
bank_statement = bank_statement.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0':'Din'})
```

Demo:

```
In [216]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 3), columns=list('abc'))

In [217]: df
Out[217]:
          a         b         c
0 -0.972161 -0.484091 -0.289475
1  1.081694  1.215217  0.241532
2 -0.581193  0.691856  0.194182

In [218]: df.columns
Out[218]: Index(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='object')
```

let's hack it:

```
In [219]: df.columns.values[0] = 'Din'
```

it seemed to work:

```
In [220]: df.columns
Out[220]: Index(['Din', 'b', 'c'], dtype='object')
```

but:

```
In [221]: df['Din']
...
skipped
...
KeyError: 'Din'
```

**Surprise!** Pandas still thinks it has an `a` column:

```
In [222]: df['a']
Out[222]:
0   -0.972161
1    1.081694
2   -0.581193
Name: Din, dtype: float64
```

**Workaround:**

```
In [224]: df.columns = ['Din'] + df.columns.tolist()[1:]

In [225]: df.columns
Out[225]: Index(['Din', 'b', 'c'], dtype='object')

In [226]: df['Din']
Out[226]:
0   -0.972161
1    1.081694
2   -0.581193
Name: Din, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed response!

Comment: Out of curiosity - 
df.columns.values[0] = 'Din' does not work! Do you know what is the reason for it? Is it a bug (since an API is provided but it does not work) or is there a valid reason for it to behave the way it behaves ?