# PandaSQLException : Can not find a column that is present in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandasql

I have imported a CSV file in to a dataframe. When I try to run a PandasSQL query on this dataframe I always get this error. I did check the column names in the dataframe using the df.columns function.

> PandaSQLException: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: CaseNo 
>   [SQL: '\nselect CaseNo \nfrom df_unhcr_interventions\n']

Thanks!

```
query = """
select CaseNo 
from df_unhcr_interventions
"""

ps.sqldf(query, locals())
```

> PandaSQLException: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: CaseNo
>   [SQL: '\nselect CaseNo \nfrom df_unhcr_interventions\n']

Sample data of the dataframe is below

** [{'CreatedDate': '4/24/2018 10:03:31 AM',
  'Org': 'NRC',
  'ProvidedDate': '4/29/2018 12:00:00 AM',
  'Quantity': 11,
  'Value': 1.0,
  'assistanceTypeName': 'Mattress',
  'currencyName': 'JD',
  '\ufeffCaseNo': '631-16C02854'},
 {'CreatedDate': '5/3/2018 8:56:29 AM',
  'Org': 'NRC',
  'ProvidedDate': '5/1/2018 12:00:00 AM',
  'Quantity': 4,
  'Value': 1.0,
  'assistanceTypeName': 'Mattress',
  'currencyName': 'JD',
  '\ufeffCaseNo': '388-12C05734'},
 {'CreatedDate': '11/10/2018 1:55:41 PM',
  'Org': 'NRC',
  'ProvidedDate': '11/10/2018 12:00:00 AM',
  'Quantity': 4,
  'Value': 1.0,
  'assistanceTypeName': 'Mattress',
  'currencyName': 'JD',
  '\ufeffCaseNo': '841-13C01123'},
 {'CreatedDate': '1/10/2019 9:37:02 AM',
  'Org': 'NRC',
  'ProvidedDate': '1/8/2019 12:00:00 AM',
  'Quantity': 2,
  'Value': 1.0,
  'assistanceTypeName': 'Mattress',
  'currencyName': 'JD',
  '\ufeffCaseNo': '631-14c20536'},
 {'CreatedDate': '3/12/2019 11:10:42 AM',
  'Org': 'NRC',
  'ProvidedDate': '3/12/2019 12:00:00 AM',
  'Quantity': 10,
  'Value': 1.0,
  'assistanceTypeName': 'Mattress',
  'currencyName': 'JD',
  '\ufeffCaseNo': '631-16C03478'}]
df_unhcr_interventions
query = """
**

Comment: Do a df.columns and check the values, Is there any leading or trailing spaces in your column names?

Comment: Tried that! The column name I am using is the exact same one I am getting when I check using df.columns

Comment: can you craete an example, probably provide a sample dataset, test your sample df and post in the question. `df.head().to_dict('r')` should do . Thanks

Comment: Hi! I just posted the sample dataset! It seems the columns has some special characters in front of it! It will be great if you could suggest a way to correct this

Comment: Hi! The problem is resolved! I used a 'utf-8-sig' when importing the CSV file. Everything works very well now! Thanks for the help @anky_91

Comment: Try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28535067/unable-to-remove-unicode-char-from-column-names-in-pandas and it will reove \u in your column names